# Best service to backup from ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, backup

I have a home server based on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I use it as a home backup system for the various computers around the house.

I would like to have a backup of my backup that is not on-site.

I am interested in an online backup service that:

- is reliable
- is easy to set up on ubuntu server
- allows me to encrypt my backups as I choose before I upload them (i.e. not necessarily using the encryption method offered by the service)
- offers affordable packages (i have about 1TB of data I would ideally like to upload the 1st time, and then of course have it do incremental backups)

Would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered CrashPlan? They support Linux (I'm running it from my Ubuntu 14.04 server) and they offer unlimited storage for a reasonable cost. If you're in the USA they also have the option of shipping a seed drive so you don't have to upload that 1 TB of initial backup.

They have 2 encryption options, one where your account password is your encryption/decryption key, another where you have a separate encryption/decryption key. It doesn't play well with local encryption from what I can tell.

I've been using it for the last 5 years. I've had no issues with backups, or restores.